# Can DebuggerBrowsableState.Never be made default for properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

In C# we can use DebuggerBrowsable attribute with DebuggerBrowsableState.Never option to hide it from debugger.

This helps me for my View Model classes which have a lot of properties which causes me to scroll for what I need to check. I always see items in the debugger like:

```
...
 Id = 5
 id = 5
...
```

And I don't want to see properties in most cases. Is it possible to automatically set state for properties as DebuggerBrowsableState.Never?

One method to automate this is to add a code snippet for generating the the DebuggerBrowsable attribute with property generation.

Yet if possible I would like to do it the other way (without too much performance loss somehow).

Automatically set all property states to DebuggerBrowsableState.Never - keep fields as they are. For exceptional cases I would specifically change state to DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed.

This would result in much cleaner code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How would this result in cleaner code?  You have a class with properties - end of.  Those properties are used in the application.  Sounds like you might have some form of anaemic domain model?  Hiding in debugger wont make it cleaner.

Comment: @HansPassant may you be confusing the attribute with DebuggerStepThrough attribute? The one I say is DebuggerBrowsable attribute which is basically not showing the variables in the watch window. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: You are right, I could not imagine anybody wanting to do this.  Sorry.

Comment: @Andez you are right - I meant my View Model classes - I am using WPF. What I want is to hide duplicate Property names for each field in my debugger watch window (for the most part they contain code for calling Property Changed events). Yet what I do not want is to put this DebuggerBrowsable attribute to every property on the view model - it creates extra clutter. I am correcting the question phrase